# How to fire following command from vc++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, command-prompt, exif

I want to change image's exif data. For that I've used [Exiv2.exe](http://www.exiv2.org/download.html). Now I want to fire command from my program which is written in vc++ 08. For modify GPS data of image, exive command is

`exiv2 -M"set Exif.GPSInfo.GPSLatitude 4/1 15/1 33/1" D:\test\image.jpg`

I've placed exiv2.exe into system32 folder. And this command works fine from command prompt. For example,

```
C:\Users\Me>exiv2 -M"set Exif.GPSInfo.GPSLatitude 4/1 15/1 33/1" D:\test\image.jpg
```

Now how can I fire this same command from my c++ program?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it,

```
const char *change_latitude = "exiv2 -M\"set Exif.GPSInfo.GPSLatitude 14/1 15/1 13/1\" D:\\test\\image.jpg";
system(change_latitude);
```

In this example assumption is : exiv2.exe in system32 folder.

Thanks...

Comment: The real assumption is that `exiv2.exe` is somewhere in the `%PATH%`, and `system32` is **not** the right directory to store random executables.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation for [ShellExecute()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [CreateProcess()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - either of these ought to get you where you want to be.

Comment: I've tried     ShellExecute(NULL, _T("open"), _T("cmd"), _T(" /C exiv2 -M\"set Exif.GPSInfo.GPSLatitude 41/1 41/1 41/1\" " "D:\test\image.jpg"), _T(" C:\ "), SW_SHOW); but not working.

Comment: ShellExecuteW( NULL, NULL, L"notepad.exe", L"c:\\temp\\foo.txt", NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL ) works for me.  You should be able to replace my parameters with yours